# Bootstrap 5 hide modal using java script

Tags: bootstrap-modal, hide, bootstrap-5

I open modal using

```
document.getElementById('openLoginFormBTN').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        let loginFormModal= new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('loginModal'));
          loginFormModal.show();
    });
```

and it works fine, but when I want to close it in function

```
...
console.log("user logged in")
let loginFormModal= new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('loginModal'));
loginFormModal.hide();
...
```

It doesn't want to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can rely on the `getOrCreateInstance` method.
No need to retreive the modal again once you have the instance.

```
const btnShow = document.getElementById('openLoginFormBTN');
const modalEl = document.getElementById('loginModal');
const loginFormModal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(modalEl);

btnShow.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    loginFormModal.show();
});

loginFormModal.hide();
```

I created a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/yg28kspf/) where you can play around with this.
Not sure if I've hit the mark on your use case. Please elaborate in case I missed something.